# Cassandra LIMIT 1 is not optimized

Tags: cassandra, limit

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS details (
    public_id text,
    updated_at timeuuid,
    details text,
    PRIMARY KEY (public_id, updated_at)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (updated_at DESC)
AND comment='A table to hold details update history'
```

***public_id*** - PartitionKey - String (uuid)

***updatedAt*** - clusteringKey - timeuuid

***details*** - json, size ranges from 1KB - 4 KB

Query - `select * from details where public_id = 'prefix_4758a709fae94c87a84ea89623037577' limit 1;`

I looked at the article - https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2017/03/07/The-limit-clause-in-cassandra-might-not-work-as-you-think.html

As the article mentioned, this was fixed in 3.4 - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8180

My version - Cassandra 4.0.5

But looking at the trace output below, it seems to be not working, as you can see

```
Merged data from memtables and 19 sstables

Merged data from memtables and 21 sstables
```

[image]
[image]

Here is tracing for another partition

- speculative retry to 3 nodes
- In total with RF 3 and CL= LOCAL_QUORUM, 6 nodes been hit, weird

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does it matter which compaction strategy we are using? Currently we are using default - SizeTierCompaction

Comment: I am not able to recreate this locally ( single node )

Comment: Running cassandra-stress to see if I can replicate it

Comment: About how many rows are under each `public_id`?

Comment: Each public_id should have at max 100 rows. But we had a bug (fixed) which was inserting upto 10,000 rows per partition (100MB+). I deleted all the rows, except latest. Currently repair is running for days and showing estimate time of completion 13 days.

Comment: Also we always use only the latest row from partition, so limit 1 is the only query we are running.
`select * from details where public_id = 'prefix_4758a709fae94c87a84ea89623037577' limit 1;`

Dows it make sense to batch (during insert) `DELETE and INSERT`, i.e to say delete all the old rows and insert a new one. Will it improve or worsen (tombstone) the read performance?

Comment: FYI currently we never issue a DELETE query and current TTL is 1 year

Comment: the above tracing output is for a one of those fat partition, lemme share the tracing for a regular (with 10-15 rows) partition as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-19345
Looks like, regressed and lost the optimization from CASSANDRA-8180